# How does ReactiveTableViewSource<TSource> work?

Tags: mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.ios, reactiveui

In our app we use ReactiveUI to follow the MVVM pattern. In one view we want to show a UITableView. Data are usually passed to a UITableView.Source but with ReactiveUI we use `ReactiveTableViewSource<TSource>`.

What I don't understand is how I can bind my data that I got in my view model in a `ReactiveList` to the `ReactiveTableViewSource`.

What we now have is that we create a table inside a UIView like this:

```
Table = new UITableView(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
Table.Source = new TableSource(Table, MyReactiveList, (NSString) CellIdentifier, _cellHeight, cell => Debug.WriteLine(cell));
```

Btw: What is the cell action used for?

Furthermore we have a Table source class that looks like this:

```
internal sealed class TableSource : ReactiveTableViewSource<MyListObject>
{
  public TableSource(UITableView tableView, IReactiveNotifyCollectionChanged<MyListObject> collection, NSString cellKey, float sizeHint, Action<UITableViewCell> initializeCellAction = null) : base(tableView, collection, cellKey, sizeHint, initializeCellAction)
```

In my view model I have a service that is updating my ReactiveList. It looks like this:

```
public sealed class MyService : ReactiveObject, IMyService
{
  public IReactiveList<MyListObject> MyReactiveList { get; }

  public async Task UpdateMyReactiveListAsync() {//...}
```

Where do I bind the table source to the ReactiveList? Where do I subscribe for events? Is there any documentation or example code I might have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with ReactiveTableViewSource is quite easy:

Just connect the List with your UITableView

```
var tableView = new UITableView ();

// Bind the List agains the table view
// SampleObject is our model and SampleCell the cell
ViewModel.WhenAnyValue (vm => vm.Items).BindTo<SampleObject, SampleCell> (tableView, 46, cell => cell.Initialize());
```

Then create a custom cell where you bind the model data against the cell.

```
public class SampleCell : ReactiveTableViewCell, IViewFor<SampleObject>
{
    public SampleCell () : base() { }
    public SampleCell (IntPtr handle) : base(handle) { }

    private SampleObject _viewModel;
    public SampleObject ViewModel
    {
        get { return _viewModel; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged (ref _viewModel, value); }
    }

    object IViewFor.ViewModel
    {
        get { return ViewModel; }
        set { ViewModel = value as SampleObject; }
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        this.WhenAnyValue (v => v.ViewModel.Name).BindTo (
            this,
            v => v.TextLabel.Text);
    }
}
```

A compelling example you can find here: https://github.com/reicheltp/ReactiveTableViewSource-Sample

**Update 2016/03/09:** Better do binding in a separated Initialize method to prevent multiple calls.

If you have more questions you can ask me on twitter: @reicheltp

Answer (score 2):

May be you miss this https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/275eca3dc2e5fc93bddb137e60be32885f788688/docs/basics/rx-cocoa-delegates.md

To subscribe the event you can assign a UITableViewDelegateRx

```
var tvd = new UITableViewDelegateRx ();
Table.Delegate = tvd;
tvd.RowSelectedObs.Subscribe (c => { });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to make a small update using ReactiveUI version 9.16.6:

Example that lists some cities with their according postal codes.

- => My ViewController inherites from ReactiveViewController
- => My CityViewModel inherites from ReactiveObject
- => My CityItemViewModel inherites from ReactiveObject
- => My CityTableViewCell inherites from ReactiveTableViewCell

  ```
  public class CityViewModel : ReactiveObject
  {
      private ICityService CityService { get; }

      private SourceCache<CityItemViewModel, int> _citiesCache;
      private IObservable<IChangeSet<CityItemViewModel, int>> _citiesOperations => _citiesCache.Connect();

      public readonly ReadOnlyObservableCollection<CityItemViewModel> Cities;

      public CityViewModel(ICityService cityService)
      {
          CityService = cityService;
      }

      #region CityViewModelCommand
      public ReactiveCommand<CityItemViewModel, Unit> CityClickCommand { get; }
      #endregion

      private async Task<IEnumerable<CityItemViewModel>> SearchCitiesAsync(string searchText, CancellationToken token)
      {
          IEnumerable<CityItemViewModel> items;

          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
              items = await CityService.ToListWithCountryCodeAsync(cancellationToken: token);
          else
              items = await CityService.ToListBySearchWithCountryCodeAsync(searchText, cancellationToken: token);

          _citiesCache.Edit(innerList =>
          {
              innerList.Clear();
              innerList.AddOrUpdate(items);
          });

          return items;
      }
  }

  public class CityItemViewModel : ReactiveObject
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public string PostalCode { get; set; }
      public override string ToString()
          => $"[CityItemViewModel: Id={Id}, Name={Name}, PostalCode={PostalCode}]";

      public CityItemViewModel() : base()
      {

      }
  }
  ```

In my ViewController's ViewDidLoad method:

```
 this.WhenActivated((cleanup) =>
            {
                this.Bind(ViewModel,
                        x => x.SearchText,
                        x => x.searchBar.Text)
                    .DisposeWith(cleanup);

                this.WhenAnyValue(v => v.ViewModel.Cities)
                    .BindTo<CityItemViewModel, CityTableViewCell>(tableView, CityTableViewCell.Key, 50, cell => cell.Initialize(),
                        source => source.ElementSelected.InvokeCommand(ViewModel.CityClickCommand))
                    .DisposeWith(cleanup);
            });
```

In my Initialize method of my UITableViewCell:

```
public void Initialize()
        {
            this.WhenAnyValue(v => v.ViewModel.Name)
                .Subscribe(name => cityLabel.Text = name);

            this.WhenAnyValue(v => v.ViewModel.PostalCode)
                .Subscribe(x => postalCodeLabel.Text = x);
        }
```

Hope that can help someone ;)