# How to bind IReadonlyReactiveList to ReactiveCollectionView

Tags: xamarin.ios, reactiveui

I have a view model that retrieve a list of data from rest service, and store inside a property.

```
private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<IReadOnlyReactiveList<Customer>> _searchResultCustomer;
public IReadOnlyReactiveList<Customer> SearchResultCustomer => _searchResultCustomer.Value;
```

I am trying to do a binding between `SearchResultCustomer` to `ReactiveCollectionView` like this `this.OneWayBind(ViewModel, vm => vm.SearchResultCustomer, v => v.cvResult.DataSource);`.

Without surprise it doesn't work, and the type expected from `v.cvResult.DataSource` is `IUICollectionViewDataSource`.

How do I solve this, is there any available example for Xamarin.IOS? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding to a UI collection, such as UITableView or UICollectionView, works a bit differently. Conveniently, you don't even need to create your own UICollectionViewSource. Just create a custom cell with an initialize method and bind like this:

```
ViewModel.WhenAnyValue(vm => vm.SearchResultCustomer).BindTo<Customer, CustomerCell>(collectionView, cell => cell.Initialize());
```

Credit to Paul Reichelt at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35750732/how-does-reactivetableviewsourcetsource-work) who answered a similar question, except for UITableView.

I forked his example project and added a working example for UICollectionView. I use IReactiveList instead of IReadOnlyReactiveList, but you should be able to modify it to fit your needs. Here's the [source](https://github.com/cabauman/ReactiveTableViewSource-Sample). Hope it helps.